# PIXI V5 PIXI.Loader() Can't not add to image container

Tags: pixi.js

I uses PIXI V5, but Can't not add to image container ...

```
const app = new PIXI.Application({
  view: document.getElementById('main'),
});

const container = new PIXI.Container();
app.stage.addChild(container);


const loader = new PIXI.Loader();
loader
  .add('imgtest','https://fakeimg.pl/100/')
  .load((loader, resources) => {
    const sprite = new PIXI.Sprite(loader.resources.imgtest.texture);
    container.addChild(sprite);
  });
```

I Try `console.log(loader.resources.imgtest.texture)` is undefined...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loaded texture wouldn't have been available when the stage was initially  rendered, so add:
`const renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer();` and call `renderer.render(container);` once the image is loaded.

By the way you can use `new PIXI.Sprite(resources.imgtest.texture)`, omitting `loader.`

Also, I'm not sure if a generated image with no .png or jpg extension will work via pixi.

Comment: i try it 

`const img = PIXI.Texture.from('https://fakeimg.pl/100/');
const sp = new PIXI.Sprite(img);
container.addChild(sp);`

is OK

Answer (score 2):

Pixi v5 does not use the same api as the previous versions and they already have a loader within the application class that you can access with `PIXI.Loader.shared`. You can assign it to a variable, but I just use the below in my application:

```
PIXI.Loader.shared
    .add('myImage', 'assets/myImage.png')
    .load((loader, resources) => {
        const sprite = new PIXI.Sprite(resources.myImage.texture);
        container.addChild(sprite);
 });
```

With this syntax, you map the image to the id you give it as the first argument.